# Asynchronous Tcpclient port check

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcpclient

I think this port check needs to be asynchronous. The listener seems to die on getting a second connection. Is the commented out bit the right way to do this? Does this require async and await?

```
public void IPPortCheck(string ip, string port)
{
    try
    {
        using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port))
        {

           //if (client.Connected == true)
           //{
                 client.SendTimeout = 1000;
           //}
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException Ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: if it doesn't raise an exception, the connection succeed. If you want to scan multiple ports, Try using `Parallel.Foreach(....)`

Comment: There's not enough information here to find out what's going wrong. This is a client - the part that connects to the listener. If you're having problems with the listener failing after its first connection request, you should dig into whats wrong with the listener, and not this class. All this class does is try to open a connection and then close it. Since a TCP listener is usually a completely open port, it should be designed to handle connections from anywhere and thus be able to deal with unexpected input/events. Sounds like it's not.